# OCaml: How to Construct AST during LL Parsing without stack

Tags: parsing, ocaml, abstract-syntax-tree

I wrote a predictive parser for a LL1 grammar. Each nonterminal `A` has a corresponding `parseA` method, which takes in a tokenlist, and returns the remainder of tokenlist and a parse tree.

**I'm confused about which AST method to call in my parser. Is there a general approach to figuring this out?**

This is my attempt:

Take for instance a subsection of my grammar:

```
expr -> t eprime 
eprime -> PLUS t eprime | MINUS t eprime | ε
t -> t tprime
tprime -> TIMES f tprime | DIVIDE f tprime | ε
f -> LPAREN expr RPAREN | LITERAL | TRUE | FALSE | ID
```

I have four parse methods, one for each nonterminal.

```
let parseExpr tokenlist =
    match tokenlist.head with 
    | "LPAREN" -> let t_expr tokenlist_t = next tokenlist |> parseExpr in 
                  let e_expr tokenlist_e = parseEPrime tokenlist_t in
                  (tokenlist_e, Ast.Expression(t_expr, e_expr))
    | "LITERAL" -> let t_expr tokenlist_t = next tokenlist |> parseExpr in 
                  let e_expr tokenlist_e = parseEPrime tokenlist_t in
                  (tokenlist_e, Ast.Expression(t_expr, e_expr))
    | "TRUE" -> let t_expr tokenlist_t = next tokenlist |> parseExpr in 
                  let e_expr tokenlist_e = parseEPrime tokenlist_t in
                  (tokenlist_e, Ast.Expression(t_expr, e_expr))
    | "FALSE" -> let t_expr tokenlist_t = next tokenlist |> parseExpr in 
                  let e_expr tokenlist_e = parseEPrime tokenlist_t in
                  (tokenlist_e, Ast.Expression(t_expr, e_expr))
    | "ID" -> let t_expr tokenlist_t = next tokenlist |> parseExpr in 
                  let e_expr tokenlist_e = parseEPrime tokenlist_t in
                  (tokenlist_e, Ast.Expression(t_expr, e_expr))


let parseEPrime tokenlist =
  match tokenlist with
   | "PLUS" -> let expr_t tokenlist_t = next tokenlist |> parseT in
                let expr_eprime tokenlist_e = parseEPrime tokenlist_t in 
                (tokenlist_e, Ast.Add(expr_t, expr_eprime))
   | "MINUS" -> let expr_t tokenlist_t = next tokenlist |> parseT in
                let expr_eprime tokenlist_e = parseEPrime tokenlist_t in 
                (tokenlist_e, Ast.Minus(expr_t, expr_eprime))
   | "SEMI" -> (tokenlist, [])
   | "RPAREN" -> (tokenlist, [])
   | _ -> raise error  


let parseT tokenlist = 
  match tokenlist.lookathead with 
  | "LPAREN" -> let expr_f tokenlist_f = parseF tokenlist in 
                let expr_tprime tokenlist_tprime = parseTprime tokenlist_f in 
                (tokenlist_tprime, Ast.F(expr_f, expr_tprime))
  | "LITERAL" -> let expr_f tokenlist_f = parseF tokenlist in 
                let expr_tprime tokenlist_tprime = parseTprime tokenlist_f in 
                (tokenlist_tprime, Ast.Literal(expr_f, expr_tprime))
  | "TRUE" -> let expr_f tokenlist_f = parseF tokenlist in 
                let expr_tprime tokenlist_tprime = parseTprime tokenlist_f in 
                (tokenlist_tprime, Ast.F(expr_f, expr_tprime))
  | "FALSE" -> let expr_f tokenlist_f = parseF tokenlist in 
                let expr_tprime tokenlist_tprime = parseTprime tokenlist_f in 
                (tokenlist_tprime, Ast.F(expr_f, expr_tprime))
  | "ID" -> let expr_f tokenlist_f = parseF tokenlist in 
                let expr_tprime tokenlist_tprime = parseTprime tokenlist_f in 
                (tokenlist_tprime, Ast.F(expr_f, expr_tprime))
  | _-> raise error

let parseTprime tokenlist = 
  match  tokenlist.lookathead with
  | "TIMES" -> let expr_f tokenlist_f = next tokenlist |> parseF in 
                let expr_tprime tokenlist_tprime = parseTPrime tokenlist_f in 
                (tokenlist_tprime, Ast.Times(expr_f, expr_tprime))
  | "DIVIDE" -> let expr_f tokenlist_f = next tokenlist |> parseF in 
                let expr_tprime tokenlist_tprime = parseTPrime tokenlist_f in 
                (tokenlist_tprime, Ast.Divide(expr_f, expr_tprime))
  | "PLUS" -> (tokenlist, [])
  | "MINUS" -> (tokenlist, [])
  | "SEMI" -> (tokenlist, [])
  | "RPAREN" -> (tokenlist, [])
  | _ -> raise error  

let parseF tokenlist = 
  match tokenlist.lookathead with
  | "LPAREN" -> let expr tokenlist_expr = next tokenlist |> parseE in 
                match next tokenlist_expr with 
                | "RPAREN" -> (next tokenlist_expr, Ast.ExpressionParen(expr))
  | "LITERAL" -> (next tokenlist, Ast.FLiteral)
  | "TRUE" -> (next tokenlist, Ast.BoolLit)
  | "FALSE" -> (next tokenlist, Ast.FBool)
  | "ID" -> (next tokenlist, Ast.Id)
  | _ -> raise error
```

As you can probably tell from my code, I wrote a type for every nonterminal, and then had a method for every production of that nonterminal.

```
(*expr -> T E* *)
type expr = 
| Expression of t eprime 


(*T -> F T*)
type t = 
| F of f * tprime

(*E* -> + T E* 
E* -> - T E* 
E* -> ε  *)
type eprime = 
| Add of t eprime
| Minus of t eprime
| Eempty


(*T* -> TIMES F T* 
T* -> / F T* 
T* -> ε*)
type tprime = 
| Divide of f * tprime 
| Times of f * tprime
| TEmpty

(*F -> LPAREN E RPAREN 
F -> Literal 
F -> TRUE 
F -> FALSE
F -> ID*)
type f = 
| ExpressionParen of expr
| Literal of int 
| BoolLit of bool 
| Id of string
```

But I don't know my approach keeps too much unnecessary information than a AST would normally shake out (I imagine an AST to be a parse tree that shakes and rids itself of unnecessary leaves). So far, I've just left off the parentheses and semi colons. I'm afraid I'm leaving too much on by having `type t, type f, type tprime, type eprime` in my AST. But if I were to remove them, I wouldn't know how to write the `type expr` in my AST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an AST defined as such:

```
type expr =
  | Add of expr * expr
  | Minus of expr * expr
  | Times of expr * expr
  | Divide of expr * expr
  | IntLit of int 
  | BoolLit of bool 
  | Id of string
```

You can adjust your parse functions to return such an AST by making the `Prime` functions take the left operand as an argument like this:

```
let parseExpr tokens =
  let (lhs, remainingTokens) = parseT tokens in
  parseExprPrime lhs remainingTokens

let parseExprPrime lhs tokens = match tokenlist.lookahead with
| PLUS :: tokens ->
  let (rhs, remainingTokens) = parseT (next tokens) in
  parseExprPrime (Add (lhs, rhs)) remainingTokens
| MINUS :: tokens ->
  let (rhs, remainingTokens) = parseT (next tokens) in
  parseExprPrime (Minus (lhs, rhs)) remainingTokens
| tokens ->
  lhs, tokens
```

`parseT` and `parseTPrime` would look the same (except with multiplication and division of course) and `parseF` would stay almost exactly as-is, except that `Ast.ExpressionParen(expr)` would just be `expr` because I've also removed the `ExpressionParen` case from the AST definition.

Note that it's not necessary to distinguish between legal and illegal tokens here. It's okay to just return `lhs, tokens` both for legal tokens like `;` or `)` and for illegal tokens. In the latter case, the illegal token will eventually detected by a calling parser - no need to detect the error in multiple places. The same is true for the expression rule: if `tokens` starts with an illegal token, that will be detected by `parseF`, so there's no need to check this here. Nor is there any need to repeat the same code four times, so you can just call `parseT` and `parseExprPrime` without even looking at the current token and those functions will take care of it.

---

As for whether simplifying the AST like this is worth it - let's consider a function `eval: expr -> int` as a case study (and let's ignore `BoolLit` and `Id` for that purpose). Using the original definition it would look like this:

```
let rec eval = function
| Expression (lhs, eprime) -> evalEPrime (evalT lhs) eprime

and evalEPrime lhsValue = function
| Add (rhs, rest) -> evalEPrime (lhsValue + evalT rhs) rest
| Minus (rhs, rest) -> evalEPrime (lhsValue - evalT rhs) rest
| Eempty -> lhsValue

and evalT = function
| T (lhs, tprime) -> evalTPrime (evalF lhs) tprime

and evalTPrime lhsValue = function
| Times (rhs, rest) -> evalTPrime (lhsValue * evalF rhs) rest
| Divide (rhs, rest) -> evalTPrime (lhsValue / evalF rhs) rest
| TEmpty -> lhsValue

and evalF = function
| ExpressionParen expr -> eval expr
| IntLit i -> i
```

Using the simplified defintiion it would instead be:

```
let rec eval = function
| Add (lhs, rhs) -> eval lhs + eval rhs
| Minus (lhs, rhs) -> eval lhs - eval rhs
| Times (lhs, rhs) -> eval lhs * eval rhs
| Divide (lhs, rhs) -> eval lhs / eval rhs
| IntLit i -> i
```

So I'd say the simplified version definitely improves working with the AST and I'd consider it worth it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems true that if you have a type for every nonterminal you'll end up with tree that's more on the concrete side (similar to a parse tree) than the abstract side.

I don't know that this is so bad, it's still a good representation of the code.

One way to look at it is that your grammar is so simple and streamlined that there's not a lot of incidental punctuation that needs to be left out to make the tree more abstract.

You could probably unify the types for expressions and terms. In other words, you could use just one internal node type for your expression trees. Once the precedences have been sorted out in the parsing, both expressions and terms are a list of subexpressions with operators between them.

Comment: I can see how I would construct one interal node type for expression trees. However, I'm lost as to how return list of subexpressions in the sub parse routines such that I can return `Ast.Expression(x, operator, y)` in `parseExpr`

Comment: The pairs of types (e, eprime) and (t, tprime) are obviously similar, and you can probably just use (e, eprime) for both (with 4 operators instead of 2). But you don't have to use a radically different structure. You can still have `Expression of e * eprime`.

Comment: I get that - I suppose I'm asking how I would still get the operators - in my current structure, if i see Add in eprime, I call Ast.Add. If I wait till ive trickled through all the productions from expr and then from expr call Ast.Expression(e, eprime) - how does it not lose the operands?

Comment: First, don't get me wrong, I think your current code is fine. Like I said it's not too concrete, really, it's just that the grammar is very streamlined. But to answer your question, just imagine that you define eprime with 5 variants (Add, Minus, Divide, Times, Empty). Then you can use the new eprime instead of the old eprime and tprime.You can still use Ast.Add and Ast.Divide like before, now they're just both constructors of eprime.